# Pandas: How to add one extra column to indicate if there is nan data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

i read the csv data into pandas like below, students got one score for every day. I want to add one extra column as "all_attendance" as extra score.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['','day1','day2','day3','day4','day5'],
                ['larry',1,4,7,3,5],
                ['niko',2,-1,3,np.nan,4],
                ['tin',np.nan,5,5, 6,7]])
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])
print(df)
```

output

```
      day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry    1    4    7    3    5
niko     2   -1    3  nan    4
tin    nan    5    5    6    7
```

I want to get result below, `1` if student had score every day, ´0´ is there is `nan` exists

```
      day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 all_attendance
larry    1    4    7    3    5              1
niko     2   -1    3  nan    4              0
tin    nan    5    5    6    7              0
```

Comment: you mean check if any column for a row has a `nan`? `df.replace('nan',np.nan).notna().all(1).astype(int)` ?

Comment: add one column with the data to 1 if no np.nan in its row, otherwise it is 0

Comment: i like your clear statement, add as answer which I can accept, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the string `'nan'` with `np.nan` and then check if all the columns for a row is notna using **[`df.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)** on `axis=1`

```
df['all_attendance'] = df.replace('nan',np.nan).notna().all(1).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['all_attendance'] = df.ne('nan').all(1).astype(int)
```

---

```
      day1 day2 day3 day4 day5  all_attendance
larry    1    4    7    3    5               1
niko     2   -1    3  nan    4               0
tin    nan    5    5    6    7               0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `apply()` function to achieve this result. Please see below:

```py
def f(row):
    if 'nan' in row.values:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

df['all_attendance'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 data = np.array([['','day1','day2','day3','day4','day5'],
            ['larry',1,4,7,3,5],
            ['niko',2,-1,3,np.nan,4],
            ['tin',np.nan,5,5, 6,7]])
            
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
              index=data[1:,0],
              columns=data[0,1:])

 columns=df.columns
 for key,item in df.iterrows():
      for column in columns:
          if item[column]=='nan':
              df.loc[key,column]=0

 [df[column].astype(int) for column in columns if column!='']
 print(df)
 df['all_attendance']=0
 for key,row in df.iterrows():
      found=0
      for value in row[columns]:
          if value==0:
              found=1
              break

     if found==1:
         df.loc[key,'all_attendance']=0
     else:
         df.loc[key,'all_attendance']=1

 print(df)
 output:
      day1 day2 day3 day4 day5  all_attendance  
larry    1    4    7    3    5               1
niko     2   -1    3    0    4               0
tin      0    5    5    6    7               0
```